# Transforming adjaceny-matrix into an adjaceny-list

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

For the given adjacency matrix below:
 `[[0, 1, 0, 4], [1, 0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 0, 2], [4, 1, 2, 0]]`

How would I go about converting it into an adjacency list like below where each tuple is `(node,weight)`

`[[(1, 1), (3, 4)], [(0, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1)], [(1, 3), (3, 2)], [(0, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)]]`

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double comprehension:

```
a=[[0, 1, 0, 4], [1, 0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 0, 2], [4, 1, 2, 0]]
print([[(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(y) if x!=0] for y in a])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man I'm not experience in list-comprehension or enumerate so would've struggled to get to your solution. Just confirming, is the complexity here O(n^2)?

Comment: The complexity is O(n*m) where n and m are the lengths of the main and nested lists. If they're the same then it's O(n^2)! Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.